# Can't export table to CSV with PostrgreSQL: Permission Denied on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, terminal, permissions

I'm an R programmer but I'm completely new to relational databases and I have been following this tutorial to learn more about SQL, specifically with PostgreSQL: https://youtu.be/qw--VYLpxG4?t=13790. However, I'm stuck at 3:49:50 since I cannot export my new table to my Desktop as a CSV file. The file he's using is "person-car.sql" and can be found in this Google Drive folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11Drhk3mHTv1P0-rPAmP6f8bFplbaIKei?usp=sharing

Specifically, I'm trying to run the following code:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN car ON car.id = person.car_id)
TO 'C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

But when I do this, I always get the following message:

```
C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop: Permission denied
```

What should I do to solve this? I have already read through several questions here on StackOverflow but nothing seems to work for me. This may have to do with the fact that I'm using the "postgres" user instead of "Carlos", and the former doesn't have access to folders such as Desktop. Nevertheless, when I try to export to `C:/Users/Public` it doesn't work either, and I can't find a way to grant access to the "postgres" user to write on any folder at all.

I have also tried exporting to `C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/file.csv` instead of just `C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop` but it doesn't work.

What are the alternatives in this situation? I'm only using the SQL shell, not pgAdmin. I'm also using Windows 8.1 by the way. Thanks you very much.

Comment: `DELIMETER` should be `DELIMITER`, are sure there is not another error?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, it was a typo in my question. If I use `DELIMITER` it still throws the exact same error.

Comment: There is no `person.car_id`, another typo? Not that the query makes an sense using `person.id` either.  This looks to be more a Windows system admin problem anyway. I don't use Windows anymore(didn't need the pain), still can't you right click on the folder and grant permissions to the postgres user?

Comment: "Desktop" is a directory, so that won't work.  When you export to "Desktop/file.csv" does it fail with the same error, or a different one?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I edited the link: the original file didn't have a foreign key column (person.car_id). Now the sql file does have that column to work with. I have tried to grant permission to the postgres user by following some tutorials, but to no avail...

Comment: Hi @jjanes. It throws the same error: `C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/file.csv: Permission denied`. Originally, I only used "Desktop" because this guy does that in the video tutorial.